# Can someone please explain an efficient indexing method for deep paging using ElasticSearch?

Tags: indexing, elasticsearch

I am still trying to understand the benefits of say, one index per month, vs one type per month in one index using ElasticSearch.

In our application, users may have over 500,000 records of data to page through (of their own related userID data, multiply this by thousands of users)- offering 10-100 documents at a time.  Collected data will be, say, `UserData` and `TransactionHistory`.

The  [ElasticSearch pagination documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/pagination.html), brings across the point quite well, on why for large amounts of data, it is best to create multiple indices:

> To understand why deep paging is problematic, let’s imagine that we
>   are searching within a single index with five primary shards. When we
>   request the first page of results (results 1 to 10), each shard
>   produces its own top 10 results and returns them to the requesting
>   node, which then sorts all 50 results in order to select the overall
>   top 10.
>
> Now imagine that we ask for page 1,000—results 10,001 to 10,010.
>   Everything works in the same way except that each shard has to produce
>   its top 10,010 results. The requesting node then sorts through all
>   50,050 results and discards 50,040 of them!
>
> You can see that, in a distributed system, the cost of sorting results
>   grows exponentially the deeper we page. There is a good reason that
>   web search engines don’t return more than 1,000 results for any query.

As explained, this makes sense.

Would it be safe then to have `UserData` and `TransactionHistory` all in the same time-stamped index per month, or day or week, depending on the amount of data collected?

If so, does ES have a process for automatically creating new indices with those types based on a schedule and organize these based on, say folders (or only by naming convention?), or is the creation of these indices strictly controlled and maintained by your application software?

Answer (score 0):

You can do index management at application side, either with some scheduler or just with proper [index template](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/indices-templates.html) + `action.auto_create_index: false` in config. In later case you can just index your document to non-existing index, creating its name in runtime (i.e. based on date) and it will be created on the fly.

Talking about `UserDate` and `TransactionHistory`, it's really based on data you will put in that indexes, index/request frequency, nested/parent-child relations (if any). In general, you can have single index for such data, as it seems to be pretty small. If its so, you can even duplicate this data in timerange-sliced indexes, if you need some relations. In general, its really similar to [dimensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension_%28data_warehouse%29) and [facts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_warehouse#Facts) management in data-warehouse approach.